# C# XNA identifier expected

Tags: c#, .net, xna, identifier

I'm trying to make a random dungeon generator using [this website](http://dirkkok.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/generating-random-dungeons-part-2/) as help but the code doesn't seem to work anymore so I'mtrying to fix it and now I'm getting a C# Identifier expected error

```
public Point PickRandomCellAndMarkItVisited()
{
   Random rnd = new Random();
   Point randomLocation = new Point(rnd.Next(1, 10), rnd.Next(1, 10));
   this.[randomLocation] = true;
   return randomLocation;
}
```

Comment: `this.[randomLocation] = true;` is invalid code. You may mean `this[randomLocation] = true;` Note that in the code you link to, the `PickRandomCellAndMarkItVisited` method doesn't have a `.` after `this`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code and the [tutorial](http://dirkkok.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/generating-random-dungeons-part-1/), it looks like you're trying to mark a random cell as visited. I think you should try this instead:

```
public class Map
{

    private readonly bool[, ] cells;    
    public Point PickRandomCellAndMarkItVisited()
    {
       Random rnd = new Random();
       Point randomLocation = new Point(rnd.Next(1, 10), rnd.Next(1, 10));
       this.cells[randomLocation.X, randomLocation.Y] = true;
       return randomLocation;
    }
}
```

This will pick a random cell from the grid and mark the corresponding boolean value as true.

Comment: Then why are there the class indexer? :)

Comment: not getting any errors anymore, so that might have worked, thanks!

Comment: Sure! Glad it helped. @Krekkon, I'm not sure why the author of the tutorial added that. IMO, it would be easier just to use `this.cells` or even `cells[,].`.

Comment: Yes it was much more easier and cleaner :)